# Creating a custom java IndexColorModel

Tags: java, plot, colors

I am using a plotting package within the [Mines Java Toolkit](https://github.com/dhale/jtk) to create a color map of a 2D float array. This package allows for selection of several ColorMap fields which produce various colorbars. I am currently using a Matlab-like JET color mapping which grades from blue to red. I would like to change this to a dozen or so incremental blocks of color so that contours are more visible.

I am trying to create a custom IndexColorModel, but am struggling in implementing it. I have looked through the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html), but cannot determine which constructor to use or how to use it. I want to create an IndexColorModel with 14 increments from blue to red.

Any tips would be great!

Here is my relevant code (It is a fragment because it is part of a GUI)

```
package arrayresponse;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import edu.mines.jtk.mosaic.*;
import edu.mines.jtk.dsp.Sampling;
import edu.mines.jtk.awt.ColorMap;

public class ResponseContours {

    public static JPanel plotResponse(ARF arf){

        //float[][] ar = arf.returnResponse();
        float[][] ar = arf.getInvResponse();
        double k = arf.getK();

        PlotPanel pp = new PlotPanel();

        Sampling x = new Sampling(arf.getKX());

        PixelsView pv = pp.addPixels(x,x,ar);
        pv.setColorModel(ColorMap.JET);

        ContoursView cv = pp.addContours(x,x,ar);
        cv.setLineStyleNegative(ContoursView.Line.SOLID);
        cv.setLineColor(Color.BLACK);
        cv.setContours(10); //initial number of contours

        PlotFrame frame = new PlotFrame(pp);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(PlotFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pp.addTitle("Array Response Function");
        pp.addColorBar("AMP");
        pp.setHLabel("kx");
        pp.setVLabel("ky");

        frame.pack();
        JPanel jp = pp;
        return jp;

    } //end of plotResponse

} //end of program
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different ways to construct an IndexColorModel.  The constructor using separate red, green and blue byte arrays has worked well for me.  Here is an example to get you started.

```
/**
 * Generates an IndexedColorModel containing 256 colors. 240 of the colors are generated by combining 6 evenly spaced red values with
 * 8 evenly spaced greens and 5 evenly spaced blue values.  The theory is that human perception is more sensitive to green and less sensitive to blue.
 * The 240 sampled colors contain black and white but do not contain any pure gray values. A 15 shade gray color ramp is added.  The final color
 * is a greenish-black and designated as the transparent color.
 * @return IndexColorModel
 */
public static IndexColorModel get685ColorModel()
{
    int r[] = {0, 51, 102, 153, 204, 255};  // 6 reds
    int g[] = {0, 36, 73, 109, 146, 182, 219, 255};  // 8 greens
    int b[] = {0, 63, 127, 191, 255};  //  5 blues

    byte[] red = new byte[256];
    byte[] green = new byte[256];
    byte[] blue = new byte[256];

    int i = 0;

    // Sample color cube.
    for (int j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < g.length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < b.length; l++) {
                red[i] = (byte) r[j];
                green[i] = (byte) g[k];
                blue[i] = (byte) b[l];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add gray ramp
    int grayIncr = 16;
    int gray = 16;
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        red[i] = (byte) gray;
        green[i] = (byte) gray;
        blue[i] = (byte) gray;
        i++;
        gray += grayIncr;
    }

    // Saved room for one more color.
    // The hope is that we can avoid giving up pure white or pure black and use this extra color as transparent.
    // Can be pretty much anything that isn't already used.  Greenish - Black.
    red[255] = 0;
    green[255] = 1;
    blue[255] = 0;

    return new IndexColorModel(8, 256, red, green, blue, 255);
}
```